# Equation for black hole modeled as changing index of refraction

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, refraction

A similar question was asked  [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112709/black-holes-behaviour-of-light-near-an-event-horizon) but i would like to know what the exact formula is for index of refraction as a function of radius that will give the same bending of light as a non rotating black hole.

Comment: Have you checked the journal reference given at the bottom of the article in the question you link ?

Comment: I looked but there weren't any equations in it. I also found a couple of non paywalled journal articles on related topics but they were too advanced given my current GR background.